# NSDebugDescription = "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.";

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking

I am using `AFJSONRequestOperation` to request a server and parse the returned JSON response, but while parsing, I got this error:

```
NSDebugDescription = "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.";
```

I checked the API and it's returning JSON data:

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
$arr[] = array("Message" => "update succeeded");
echo '{"Result":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

Any idea how to fix that?

**EDIT**

I tried to call the API from browser and include the request in the url, and so I got a valid JSON response:

```
{"Result":[{"Message":"update succeeded"}]}
```

Comment: Could you post the JSON string that is received by `AFJSONRequestoperation`.

Comment: Hi, the JSON I got in the failure block is `(null)`

Comment: can you run the api in browser and include the response to the question?

Comment: Yeah I did already, please have a look on my edit :)

Comment: I don't know PHP but shouldn't the entire thing you echo be wrapped in a JSON_encode?

Comment: JSON response is valid so I assume you made some error with getting the response. Can you post how you request the data?

Comment: Yup, paste some OBJC here.

Comment: shouldn't the content type be application/json ? Also, a lot of JSON deserializer expected the JSON string to be encoded in UTF8 without BOM

Answer (score 1):

First thing, `json_encode` the entire object rather than breaking into it pieces.

Secondly, unless $arr contains multiple elements (not clear from example above), it should be initalized as thus:

`$arr = array("Message" => "update succeeded");`

I'm still not certain what else could be the issue here. You should echo out what your app is receiving and that should indicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please use acceptable content type.
in your webservice that should be only plain text.

here is my swift code and fixed:

```
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

    manager.requestSerializer=AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer();

    manager.GET(

        baseURL + (webServiceType as String) + secureParam,
        parameters:[:],

        success:
        { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
            responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            completion(obj: responseObject)
        },
        failure:
        { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
            error: NSError!) in
            completion(obj: nil)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Check you have added /api/ before your base url of API like

http:// someurl / yourBasrUrl /api/apiName

Answer (score 1):

To make a valid json response, your code should
look something like this:

```
$response = array(
    "Result" => array(
        "Message" => "update succeeded"
    )
)

echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need read fragment json you can use option `.allowFragments` like this:

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: someData, options: .allowFragments)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your API is returning improper `Content-Type`. Proper content type for JSON data is `application/json`. This may be conflicting while using third-party libraries.

Secondary, you should not produce json string "by hand". Altogether API should be modified to face:

```php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$arr[] = array("Message" => "update succeeded");
echo json_encode(array('Result' => $arr));
```

Last bat not least. There is one more thing in charge possible: you might have BOM characters at very beginning of your api PHP script. Those are whitespace, so you may not see them in browser. Please, [ensure that your PHP files are encoded without BOM](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+file+without+BOM).